# Solve Recurrence T(n) = 4T(n/4) + n*[log(n)]^2

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation, master-theorem

I am trying to solve

```
T(n) = 4*T(n/4) + n*[log(n)]^2
```

I decided to use Master Theorem so I found a,b=4 and logb(a)=1.
I thought that 3rd case is the solution but I don't know actually how to solve this.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the numbering of cases as per this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)), we see that our recurrence follows the second case and hence,
$$ T(n) = \Theta\left( n \log^3n \right) $$

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and for the link you send! Could you please tell me how this could be solved with the other methods? I hope I don't become tedious. Anyway thanks :) @kodwx